# Better way to write this code rather than 2x foreach?

Tags: c#

```
    List<CormantRadPane> panesToSave = new List<CormantRadPane>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RadPaneSetting> paneState in RadControlStates.PaneStates)
    {
        CormantRadPane pane = Utilities.FindControlRecursive(Page, paneState.Key) as CormantRadPane;
        panesToSave.Add(pane);
    }

    foreach (CormantRadPane pane in panesToSave)
    {
        RadControlSave.SavePane(pane);
    }
```

RadControlSave.SavePane(pane) modifies the RadControlStates.PaneStates collection. Is there a nicer way to write this code in this situation?

EDIT: Everyone please read what I wrote literally right above this. Jimmy posted an obvious solution that I hadn't though about -- creating a copy of the collection right before iterating through it so that RadControlSave does not modify the collection being iterated upon.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Better" ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the objects used, but what is preventing you from moving RadControlSave.SavePane(pane); to the initial foreach? in both contexts pane is a CormantRadPane object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way would be to call ToArray() on PaneStates (to make a copy, because you can't modify the sequence inside the foreach)

```
foreach(var state in RadControlStates.PaneStates.ToArray()) {
    var pane = Utilities.FindControlRecursive(Page, state.Key) as CormantRadPane;
    RadControlSave.SavePane(pane);
}
```

Comment: Ahh. Yes. Good call. Thanks for seeing that.

Answer (score 0):

Since calling RadControlSave.SavePane() modifies the collection, there's really no better way to do this.

Considering there's nothing fundamentally wrong with this code, I wouldn't worry about it too much. You could use LINQ, though, to make it look a little cleaner (even though it would be doing the same fundamental thing underneath):

```
var panesToSave = RadControlStates.PaneStates
    .Select(ps => Utilities.FindControlRecursive(Page, ps.Key) as CormantRadPane)
    .ToList();

foreach(var pane in panesToSave)
{
    RadControlSave.SavePane(pane);
}
```

I'm not familiar with any of those static methods though. If there's a way you could rewrite them to not modify the state of the collection...that would be preferable (it would allow you to do all the work in a single loop).

**Update**

You could also clone the original collection and combine the work in a single loop:

```
foreach(var kvp in RadControlStates.PaneStates.ToList())
{
    RadControlSave.SavePane(
        Utilities.FindControlRecursive(Page, paneState.Key) as CormantRadPane
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do the `SavePane()` in the first `foreach`?

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RadPaneSetting> paneState in RadControlStates.PaneStates)
{
    CormantRadPane pane = Utilities.FindControlRecursive(Page, paneState.Key) as CormantRadPane;
    RadControlSave.SavePane(pane);
}
```

Comment: As stated, RadControlSave.SavePane modifies the collection so I couldn't do this so simplistically. It looks like Jimmy hit the obvious answer on the head.

Comment: @Sean Admittedly I don't know these controls, but why does the panestate collection changing matter in this example?  Is the collection getting added to / removed from?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just combine them?

```
List<CormantRadPane> panesToSave = new List<CormantRadPane>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RadPaneSetting> paneState in RadControlStates.PaneStates)
{
    CormantRadPane pane = Utilities.FindControlRecursive(Page, paneState.Key) as CormantRadPane;
    RadControlSave.SavePane(pane);
    panesToSave.Add(pane);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
  List<CormantRadPane> panesToSave = new List<CormantRadPane>();



  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RadPaneSetting> paneState in RadControlStates.PaneStates)
  {
        CormantRadPane pane = Utilities.FindControlRecursive(Page, paneState.Key) as CormantRadPane;
        //panesToSave.Add(pane);
        RadControlSave.SavePane(pane);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could, instead of add it (in the first foreach) just save it

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a collection of the Panes you're trying to save (instead of FindControlRecursive?)

Then you could use LINQ on that collection like:

```
foreach(var pane in Panes.Where(p => p.IsPane))
{
    RadControlSave.SavePane(pane);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the panesToSave List neccessary why not simply have:

```
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, RadPaneSetting> paneState in RadControlStates.PaneStates)     
    {         
    CormantRadPane pane = Utilities.FindControlRecursive(Page, paneState.Key) as CormantRadPane;         
    RadControlSave.SavePane(pane);    
    }
```

Hope This Helps,
Eamonn

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
foreach (var pane in
                RadControlStates.PaneStates
                .Select(paneState => Utilities
                    .FindControlRecursive(Page, paneState.Key) as CormantRadPane))
                RadControlSave.SavePane(pane);
```